# How do you create a root node in zookeeper?

Tags: apache-zookeeper

A zookeeper create operation requires that the parent already exists. How do you create the first parent? It's turtles all the way down.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you try to create a znode with path = `'/app1'`, the parent of `znode (/app1)` already exists because the parent is `znode ('/')`.

[image: ZooKeeper's Hierarchical Namespace]

Reference: http://zookeeper.apache.org/doc/r3.1.2/zookeeperOver.html#sc_dataModelNameSpace